# How can I add additional parameters to multipart POST request?

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

I use HttpWebRequest to upload file on the server. But I also want to send some parameters (I mean name-value pairs)

Comment: What if I just add all my name-value pairs to the url? Something like that: localhost:8080/fileuploader?a=b&c=d . Should it work with POST?

Comment: see if this helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them to the query string.  They'll be available on the server, regardless of whether the HTTP method is POST or GET.

Comment: OK. but in other hand, when I send a file to the server there is a file body in the post with delimiters. So can I add my parameters string to the request body? I mean before or after file body. I am not sure how POST body should  looks like in this case.

Comment: Looks like you want the answer from this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

This uploads the name/value collection as a separate part of the multipart POST request.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("some site");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] data = "some data";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Yes, but what I want is to send both file and parameters string. What should I write in the stream first? Can you clarify how to handle the situation when "some data" is a couple of file and parameters string